# SecureRandom safety?

Tags: java, random, pseudo-random-number-generator

I need to randomly pick 10 numbers from 1 to 2000. It is very important that this rng cannot be predicted/hacked in any way. Would this be a safe/proper way to do it:

```
int randomInt;
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    randomInt = random.nextInt(2000) + 1;
    String generated = generated+String.valueOf(randomInt)+",";
}
```

I need it to securely generate those random numbers both on windows and android devices. The devices can be offline too if it helps. So would this be safe?

EDIT: I'm especially worried about android version, because I've heard bad stories in the past where people got hacked due to a bug with SecureRandom on android.

Comment: This will now generate numbers in the range 1...2001

Comment: Fixed it. I was initially doing it with int[] array but then switched to this and messed up the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate numbers within 0..2000, not 1...2000, but, yes, `SecureRandom` is the proper class here.

Use `random.nextInt(2000) + 1` for the correct range.

Comment: Oh you're right, my bad

Comment: Note the upper bound when you add 1: It should be 2000, not 2001.